# How to model multiple (>2) color polya urn processes?

Tags: r

I am trying to build a Polya Urn model. Two colours went fine, with three however I ran into some trouble.

```
ndraws<-1000; nexps<-2000; Distribution.yellow<-matrix(0,ndraws,1); for (k in       1:nexps){
red<- 1;
yellow<- 1;
blue<-1 ;
for (n in 1:ndraws){
    drawn<-sample(0:2,size=1,prob=c(red,yellow,blue)/(red+yellow +blue))
    red<-?? ;
    blue<-?? ;
    yellow<-?? ;
  }
  Distribution.yellow[k]<-yellow/(red+yellow+blue) }
```

My problem lies in translating this line of code:

```
 drawn<-sample(0:2,size=1,prob=c(red,yellow,blue)/(red+yellow +blue))
```

Into the respective extra balls added to the urn. (hence the question marks).

With two colours I did it as follows:

```
drawn<-sample(0:1,size=1,prob=c(red,blue)/(red+blue))
red<-red+(1-drawn);
blue<-blue+(drawn);
```

But this obviously does not work when there's more than two colours. How should I approach with three or more colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model), the rules for a Pólya urn process are:

> one ball is drawn randomly from the urn and its color observed; it is then returned in the urn, and an additional ball of the same color is added to the urn, and the selection process is repeated.

In other words, drawing a ball increments the number of balls of that colo(u)r by one.

So we can set up an `if` statement that adds one red ball if `drawn==0`, one yellow ball if `drawn==1`, and one blue ball otherwise ...

```
ndraws <- 1000
nexps <- 500
set.seed(101)
yellow_final <- numeric(nexps)
for (k in 1:nexps) {
    red <- 1; yellow <- 1; blue<-1
    for (n in 1:ndraws) {
        drawn <- sample(0:2,size=1,prob=c(red,yellow,blue)/(red+yellow+blue))
        if (drawn==0) {
            red <- red+1
        } else if (drawn==1) {
            yellow <- yellow+1
        } else blue <- blue+1
    }
    yellow_final[k]<-yellow/(red+yellow+blue)
}
```

A picture:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
hist(yellow_final,col="gray",freq=FALSE,
     xlab="Prop. yellow after 1000 draws")
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized solution:

```
ndraws<-1000 
nexps<-2000
colors <- c('red', 'blue', 'yellow') # add balls with other colors
initial.num.balls <- c(1,1,1) # can have different numbers of balls to start with
ball.to.observe <- 'yellow'
distribution.ball.to.observe <- replicate(nexps, {
  urn <- rep(colors, initial.num.balls) # polya's urn
  count.balls <- as.list(initial.num.balls)
  names(count.balls) <- colors
  for (i in 1:ndraws) {
    drawn <- sample(urn, 1)
    count.balls[[drawn]] <- count.balls[[drawn]] + 1
    urn <- c(urn, drawn)
  }
  count.balls[[ball.to.observe]] / sum(as.numeric(count.balls))
})
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + stat_density(aes(distribution.ball.to.observe), bw=0.01)
```

[image]